# Decrement two numeric substrings in a year span expression

Tags: php, date-range, text-parsing, decrement, hyphenation

I am trying to minus or subtract by 1 the academic year of school year with this format, e.g. `"2020-2021"`

If it is `2020-2021`, I would like to change it `2019-2020`. Is there a way to solve this concern?

I considered trying to subtract using a hyphenated expression, but I am pretty stuck.

```
echo "2020-2021"-"1-1";
echo "Result: 2019-2020";
```

Comment: [Split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [parse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), subtract each then just recombine them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode and parse the value to subtract the value

```
    $minusYear = 1;
    $myString = "2020-2021";
    $myArray = explode('-', $myString);
  
  
    foreach($myArray as $k => $v)
    {
      $myArray[$k] = (int) $myArray[$k] - $minusYear;
    }
  
    echo "Result ".$myArray[0]."-".$myArray[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to complicate your task by trying to shoehorn `1-1` into your approach.  Use `preg_replace_callback()` to target and decrement numeric substrings in one line of code.

This approach targets the numbers and therefore will not break if your delimiting character(s) change.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/l3lOA))

```
$yearSpan = '2020-2021';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', fn($m) => --$m[0], $yearSpan);
```

Decrementing the fullstring match `--$m[0]` could also be written as simple subtraction: `$m[0] - 1`.